# Jni object growing memory in java loop

Tags: java, memory, java-native-interface

When creating a JNI object in a Java loop, the memory keeps growing in the Java process.

Example:

```
class Nat{
    native void hello();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true){
           //creating jni object
           Nat nat = new Nat();
           // in this loop memory growing
       }
    }

    static{
        System.loadLibrary('Hello')
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Nat_hello(JNIEnv *, jobject){
    //NOTHING CODE.......................
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could word the question as a question. What do you want to know?

Comment: Can you put more code? How do you use the nat object in JNI call?

Answer (score 0):

Every loop pass creates a new `Nat` object which needs memory. Since the loop is always running and has no breaking condition, the memory grows really fast.

Comment: What are your exact measurement results? The JVM does escape analysis and other tricks to reduce memory usage. This code may very well use a constant amount of memory.

Comment: @rightføld - Actually, it is unlikely that escape analysis will be effective here.  1) It is not enabled by default on a lot of JVMs.  2) This is in the `main` method, and the chances are that it won't get JIT compiled soon enough.  The JIT compiler does the escape analysis ...